# in Libgdx, how to calculate the b2body's point in screen size

Tags: box2d, libgdx

[image: picture]

In libgdx I set:

```
mCam = new OrthographicCamera(100, 100 * h / w);
// mCam.position.set(50, 50, 0);
mCam.position.set(24, 150, 0);
mCam.zoom = 0.5f;
mCam.update();
```

and print a body.x = 4, y = 153

and how to calculate the point into screen point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want should probably be [`Camera.project(...)`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.html#project%28com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3%29)

It should work this way:

```
Vector3 worldCoordinates = new Vector3(body.getPosition().x, body.getPosition().y, 0);
Vector3 screenCoordinates = mCam.project(worldCoordinates);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. the code is Vector3 worldCoordinates = new Vector3(mHero.getPosition().x, mHero.getPosition().y, 0);
   mCam.project(worldCoordinates);